# What is this placeholder in the sql query?

Tags: java, sql

this is a method that I have been reading which was not made by me.
I don't understand the o in this query nor the sql language that it uses. Would anyone explain to me how it works and what its selecting?

> queryMain.append("SELECT o FROM ctrData o ");

```
 public Specification byCtr(String ctr) {

            StringBuilder queryMain = new StringBuilder();
            queryMain.append("SELECT o FROM ctrData o ");

            StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();
            clause.append("WHERE o.ctr = :ctr");

            Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<>();
            param.put("ctr", ctr);

            super.init(queryMain.toString(), clause.toString(), param);

            return this;
        }
```

Comment: `ctrData o` - the `o` is an **alias**.  It's just a shortcut, anytime you refer to ctrData, you can instead use the alias.  As in `WHERE o.ctr`, that's the same as `ctrData.ctr`.    The `select o` part looks invalid to me. Maybe `select o.*` was intended?

Comment: `o` is an alias for the table `ctrData`. This sql code should not work as you cannot select a table directly in any sql dialect afak. It seems like the author wanted to write something like `SELECT o.* FROM ....` which would select all columns of the table.

Comment: @Z.H. . . . Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Is it maybe a query for use with JPA so jpql, I know that it supports this syntax

Answer (score 0):

You have this query:

```
SELECT o
FROM ctrData o;
```

In all databases, this would be selecting a column called `o` from the table `ctrData`.  This would be equivalent to `o.o`.

In most databases, you will get an error if there is no such column.  Some databases such as Postgres support records/structs.  In these, the query will return the record associated with each row.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input. But nope there is no table_name o as it is just a placeholder. (SELECT o FROM ctrData o) would be the same as (SELECT o FROM ctrData) right?   Nope I have not learnt structs and have never used Postgres before.

Comment: @Z.H . . . Nothing in this question refers to a *table* names `o`, so I don't understand your comment.

Comment: No it is not because it is not an actual table name. Anyway, the other contributor has clarified it. It is in fact, java persistence query language. So I am researching on it

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's hard to tell what this actually is but it looks a lot like JPQL which is JPA's SQL like query language.

In JPQL the meaning of `SELECT o FROM ctrData o` would be:

- `ctrData` would be the name of an entity (i.e. a mapped data class)
- `ctrData o` would create an alias to refer to that entity
- `SELECT o FROM ctrData o` would thus mean you want to select all instances of that entity

How that translates to SQL (if at all) would depend on your application and the framework you're using (if this actually is JPQL) but it might be something like `select o.* from table_ctrData_is_mapped_to o`.

Additionally that `WHERE o.ctr = :ctr` would mean the following:

- `WHERE` is the same as in SQL, i.e. it defines a filter/where-clause for the select query
- `o.ctr` would mean that the property `ctr` in the `ctrData` entity (as aliased by `o`) should be checked
- `:ctr` is a named parameter, i.e. a placeholder so that the framework knows where to put the value for the parameter named `ctr` (see `param.put("ctr", ctr);`)

The SQL this condition would be mapped to might be something like `WHERE o.column_ctr_is_mapped_to = ?` (JDBC parameter being used here).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input!  I have searched and read up on JPQL and it looks much like it. The rest of the java codes have similar syntax. Now I have to try applying it.